# Mariadb CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gets changed to 'current_timestamp()'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So, reformatted a dev machine and blindly reinstalled the MAMP stack.  Now my mariadb is a different version than our server (10.2.6 vs 10.0.17).

After transferring the sever DBs to the dev, it seems the new version has converted all the default timestamp default values from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to 'current_timestamp()'.

Now, when transferring a db back to the server I get "Invalid default value for" timestamp fields as it will only accept CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and not current_timestamp()

Obviously we need to upgrade the sever, but in the meantime is there any way I can make my dev mariadb to actually use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and not convert?
Thanks
Rob

Comment: Which server version are you trying to switch to? Something else must be wrong with the setup. All versions of MariaDB from 5.5 through 10.2 and all MySQL from 5.5 to 5.7 accept `current_timestamp()` syntax as default value for a timestamp column.

Comment: The error is occurring on 10.0.17, although I've just tested uploading to 10.1.19 and it still throws the error.  Here's an example:

[Err] [Dtf] Transfer Data [CREATE TABLE `audit` (
 `audit_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `audit_key_value` text NOT NULL,
 `audit_time_stamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT 'current_timestamp()',
 PRIMARY KEY (`audit_id`)
) ENGINE=`InnoDB` AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT COMMENT='' CHECKSUM=0 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=0;]:
Invalid default value for 'audit_time_stamp'
[Err] [Dtf] Terminated

Comment: The problem is not `current_timestamp()`, it's the single quote marks around `current_timestamp()`, and it's unclear how you got those, just `SHOW CREATE TABLE` doesn't do it. do you remember how exactly you were taking the backup?

Comment: It's not a backup issue.  Regardless of the SQL application, mariadb is automatically converting it to 'current_timestamp()'.  It's doubly annoying as when you set up such a field in Navicat or Sequel Pro CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the only option!  grrr

Comment: What step did the naughtiness?  `mysqldump`?  `phpmyadmin`?  Something in Navicat?

Comment: I use Navicat.  The sqldump was no good either.  It also got confirmed with Heidi

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# sed 's/current_timestamp()/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP/g' current_dump_file > new_dump_file
```

This simply replaces every occurence of `current_timestamp()` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Then you can import the new dump file and there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks, that would work just fine if it were just an occaisional manual edit.  However we are currently using Navicat to do an automated transfer/upload of lots of dbs in a sitting.

Comment: I wouldn't advise that. Navicat has a nasty habit of losing primary key definitions in transit. If you are going to use it anyway, make very sure data arrives same as source. Personally I would go with a regular mysqldump and mysql import.

Comment: We've never had any issues of anything like that *yet*.  I'll look into that and see if that can help the team change habits.  At the moment it's all done via Navicat profiles. Thanks